# allocation error when trying to do shmat

Tags: c, linux

when trying to do `shmat` i get allocation error, telling me i cannot accsess the memory, it did not happen to me before and i really dont know what to do.
this is the error :

> 0xffffffffffffffff error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff

and the wiered thing is that `vecBoard`  is allocated in the process mapped area and only get crazy when `shmat` is triggered. thank you all!

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>

    #define SHM_SIZE 4096
    #define FLAGS IPC_CREAT 
    #define COLUMNS  8
    #define ROWS  8
    key_t key;    

int main()
{ 
     char* vecBoard;

    // Creating shared memory :

    if ((key = ftok("ex31.c",'k')) == -1)
    {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }
    int shm_id;
    shm_id=shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,FLAGS);
    if(shm_id==-1)
    {
        printf("error creating shared memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("the shared memory segment ID is: %d\n",shm_id);

    vecBoard = (char *)shmat(shm_id,0,0);
    if((vecBoard = (char *)shmat(shm_id,0,0)) == (char*)-1)
    {
        printf("error in attaching to the shared memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean up that mess: format&indent properly. Looks like C, not C++., If you compile as C++, chenge the tag to C++, but remove the C tag. And don't cast `void *` to pointers in C. Use the `NULL` macro for _null-pointer constant_ in C and `nullptr` in C++.

Comment: The code you shown doesn't access memory allocated( `vecBoard`). What triggers the error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

The shown code calls `shmat`() twice, for the same memory segment.

That's obviously wrong.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i deleted the first shmat ("vecBoard = (char *)shmat(shm_id,0,0); ") and the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `errno` would help diagnose the problem (i.e. call `perror` on failure instead of just `printf`).  The OS gives you information when a system call fails; don't ignore it!

If you carefully read the man page for `shmget`, the third argument (`flags`) is supposed to contain, in its low 9 bits, the permissions desired for the shared memory segment.  If you just pass `IPC_CREAT` here, those bits are cleared to 0, so you create a segment for which nobody has either read or write permissions.  Thus `shmat` fails (with `EACCES` because you are (implicitly) asking to both read and write that segment, and you don't have permission to do either.

You probably want to change it to something like `IPC_CREAT | 0600`, if you want the current user to be able to access the segment.

Note that before testing this again, you'll probably have to remove the existing shared memory segment with the erroneous permissions.  Use the `ipcs` and `ipcrm` tools for this.